# Why does my program keep responding with a zero?

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point

I am very new to programming and to test some of the things I know I thought I would try and make a program. But it keeps responding with 0 regardless of the inputs. I'm sorry if its messy, but within my framework of understanding can you show a fix?

Thanks for any help you provide.

### Code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args ) {

        // Probability of Hitting

        Console.WriteLine( "Welcome to the Ranged Death Calculator, please enter the Ballistic Skill (BS) " + Environment.NewLine + "of the model firing." );
        float BallisticSkillf = Convert.ToSingle( Console.ReadLine() );
        float WSProbabilityf;
        if( BallisticSkillf <= 5 ) {
            WSProbabilityf = Convert.ToSingle( ( BallisticSkillf / 6 ) );
        }

        else {
            WSProbabilityf = Convert.ToSingle( ( ( 5 / 6 ) ) + ( 1 / 6 * ( ( BallisticSkillf - 6 ) / 6 ) ) );
        }

        // Probability of Wounding

        Console.WriteLine( "Please enter the toughness of your target" );
        float TargetToughnessf = Convert.ToSingle( Console.ReadLine() );

        Console.WriteLine( "Please enter the strength of the Weapon firing" );
        float WeaponStrengthf = Convert.ToSingle( Console.ReadLine() );

        float WoundProbabilityf = 0;

        if( WeaponStrengthf - TargetToughnessf >= 2 )
            WoundProbabilityf = ( (float)( 5 / 6 ) );

        else if( WeaponStrengthf - TargetToughnessf == 1 )
            WoundProbabilityf = ( (float)( 4 / 6 ) );

        else if( WeaponStrengthf - TargetToughnessf == 0 )
            WoundProbabilityf = ( (float)( 3 / 6 ) );

        else if( WeaponStrengthf - TargetToughnessf == -1 )
            WoundProbabilityf = ( (float)( 2 / 6 ) );

        else if( WeaponStrengthf - TargetToughnessf <= -2 )
            WoundProbabilityf = ( (float)( 1 / 6 ) );

        //Probability of failing saving throw

        Console.WriteLine( "Please enter the relevant armour save of the target, (So, 2, would be for 2+, , 3+ etc.) (Also, take into consideration the AP Value of the weapon fired)" );
        float nTargetRelevantSave = Convert.ToSingle( Console.ReadLine() );
        float TRProbabilityf = ( (float)( ( nTargetRelevantSave - 1 ) / 6 ) );

        // Number of shots fired

        Console.WriteLine( "Finally, please enter the number of shots fired with the weapon" );
        float nShotsFromWeapon = Convert.ToSingle( Console.ReadLine() );

        // All previous values to determine likely number of wounds inflicted
        float nWoundsInflictedf = ( (float)WSProbabilityf * (float)WoundProbabilityf * (float)TRProbabilityf * (float)nShotsFromWeapon );
        Console.WriteLine( "The number of wounds you are likely to inflict is " + (float)nWoundsInflictedf );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1/6 (and other calculations) are being performed in integer math, so the result is always 0. do `1f / 6` and notice that you are now seeing floating points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation are in ints and then you cast the value to a float. You should dod the calculation with floats.

```
WoundProbabilityf = 5F / 6F;
```

Besides that you are doing calculation on floats and the an equal on a int:

```
WeaponStrengthf - TargetToughnessf == 1
```

When you use floats at the right the change of hitting the int on the right would be very snall. You can better use ranges:

```
float fHitForce = WeaponStrengthf - TargetToughnessf;
fHitForce >= 1 && fHitForce < 2
```

[Float MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
(float)(2 / 6)
```

this will cast to float the result of two integers division  2/6 = 0

to work try

```
 (float)2 / 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WoundProbabilityf = ( (float)( 5 / 6.0 ) );
```

If both numerator and denominator are integer, the result is integer. One of them has to be float. In case of variable, you can do

```
WoundProbabilityf =  (float)( 5 / (n * 1.0) );
```